# How to allow a third party to update information within an Application

Tags: android, iphone, content-management-system

At the moment i am beginning to create an android and iPhone application for a third party.

When the application is finished the third party would like to update information within the application like a news feed or new content.

What would be the best way to create a CMS(Content Management System) for the third party so they could easily create new data which can be viewed on the application.

Lets say they would just have to login to a website, give the new information, could be photos,videos, points of intrest(coordinates), text or other information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220684/are-there-any-cmscontent-management-system-for-iphone-and-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really broad question and depends on many factors: what CMS's you are already familiar with, what sort of data you need to update, what level of user experience the third party is expecting etc. You will get a better response on SO if you ask a specific question.

Having said that, I would try to decouple the iPhone implementation from the CMS implementation so you can defer choice of CMS until you are clearer about your requirements. Use something standard like an RSS feed that you can prototype and get the iPhone end working correctly then choose a CMS that can create RSS feed for you (e.g. Wordpress off the top of my head).